# Show that on local charts, a function $f : \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow L_d$ is defined by polynomials.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, projective-space, homogeneous-equation

Let $$L_d = (\mathbb{C}^{n+1}−\{0\})×\mathbb{C}/∼, \text{ where } (x_0,\dots,x_n,q)∼(λx_0,…λx_n,λ^dq).$$
Let $w(x_0, \dots, x_n)$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d.$ I've already shown that $$f:\mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow L^d$$ defined by $$[x_0:x_1:\dots:x_n] \mapsto [x_0:x_1:\dots : x_n : w(x_0, \dots, x_n)]$$ is a well-defined function. My goal is to show that on local charts it is defined by polynomials.
I know that the open charts on $L_d$ are $$U_i = \{[x_0: \dots: x_n: q] | x_i \neq 0\}$$ and the open charts on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are $$U_i = \{[x_0: \dots: x_n] | x_i \neq 0\}.$$ Are local charts the same thing as open charts?  What does it mean for the function to be defined by polynomials?

Comment: Your function was since the beginning defined by polynomials. You probably mean that it is defined by polynomial functions of the local coordinates. Then $U_i = \{ [X], X_i=1\}$, on $U_i$ the $X_j= x_j/x_i$ are rational functions $\Bbb{P}^n\to \Bbb{C}$ (whereas your $x_j$ are not) and $f$ is given by polynomials in the $X_j$.

Comment: To make it clear you need to define the function field of $\Bbb{P}^n$, which is $\Bbb{C}(x_1/x_0,\ldots,x_n/x_0)$, then a rational function is regular (ie. no poles) on $U_i$ iff it is in the subring $\Bbb{C}[x_1/x_i,\ldots,x_n/x_i]$. For each $i$, your map is given by rational functions regular on $U_i$ (those regular functions are not the same for each $i$, they give the same map on $U_i\cap U_j$ only because of the $\sim$ of $L_d$)